Neural Network Model Weight Matrix
I was trying to make the all values in my trained neural network model to zero's.
The initial model file size nearly 330 MB. But when I modified the values of weight matrix to zero's it becomes double size model. nearly 660MB.
What could be the reason for this. I check with the weight matrix shape. it doesn't changed. same for both
model_transmitter_main0 = keras.models.load_model(f"/content/drive/MyDrive/auto_encoder/models/video{the_video}/gop{the_gop}/model_transmitter_main0.h5") 

weights1 = model_transmitter_main0.get_weights() 

weights1[0] = np.zeros_like(weights1[0]) 

weights1[1] = np.zeros_like(weights1[1]) 

weights1[2] = np.zeros_like(weights1[2]) 

weights1[3] = np.zeros_like(weights1[3]) 

model_transmitter_main0.set_weights(weights1) 

# Save the modified model 

model_transmitter_main0.save("/content/drive/MyDrive/auto_encoder/existing.h5")


You should be able to shorten the whole zero-setting to wieghts1 = 0? This should broadcast the zero to all places in the array.

It must probably change of dtype. An example would be initially it was tf.float32  and when you initialised it to zero, it became tf.float64. You can check whether or not if the dtype of model changed.

No I also checked it. But the data type was not changed. it still float32 event after the conversion
